# IntelliJ IDEA search for next occurrence of selected text

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse I can highlight text in the editor such as "foobar" and then hit `Ctrl+K`, and Eclipse will automatically do a "find next" operation as if I had originally searched for "foobar". I don't have to do a separate "search" operation for the selected text. How do I do this in IntelliJ?

If I switch IntelliJ to Eclipse key mappings, indeed I can press `Ctrl+K` to invoke the "find next" operation. Unfortunately it ignores the selected text and instead searching again for the *last text I searched for*.

In other words, with Eclipse mappings in IntelliJ I still have to perform the following steps to do a `Ctrl+K` search for "foobar":

1. Select the text "foobar" in the editor.
2. Hit `Ctrl+F` for search; IntelliJ will pick up the selected text "foobar".
3. Hit `<Enter>` to search once for "foobar".
4. Hit `<Esc>` to exit search mode.
5. Finally hit `Ctrl+K` to search for the next occurrence of "foobar".

In Eclipse I only have to do this:

1. Select the text "foobar" in the editor.
2. Hit `Ctrl+K` to search for the next occurrence of "foobar" (regardless of what I searched for previously).

How can I get the same "search for next occurrence of selected text" functionality IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: But I don't want to "search for a string everywhere". I want to go to the next occurrence of the selected text, _within the current file_, with a single keystroke. How do I do that in IntelliJ? If you tell me how it's done, maybe it will convince me of how wonderful IntelliJ is. If you avoid answering the question and instead merely bash Eclipse, it makes me wonder …

Comment: Unfortunately the link you referred to indicates the IntelliJ "Next Occurence of the Word at Caret" operation, which in my testing just now seems only to work with the nearest word, _but does not work if a phrase is selected_. But thank you for your time and effort. Have a wonderful day. Not that I'm mistaking you for someone who cares whether someone wishes them a wonderful day or not. I just want to wish you a wonderful day anyway.

Comment: You can hit Ctrl+F and the "Down" arrow after that (instead of Enter).

Comment: But `Ctrl+F` followed by `Down Arrow` still leaves me in "Find" mode. I can't edit the document text. I still have to hit `Esc` to exit "Find" mode and go back to "Edit" mode. I don't want to go into "Find" mode at all. I just want to search for the next occurrence of the selected text, immediately, with a single keypress—just like I can with Eclipse `Ctrl+K`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Quick Find](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10635-quick-find) plugin, which appears to emulate the Eclipse functionality more closely than the "Next Occurrence of the Word at Caret" action. Caveat: I have not tried it myself.

Comment: "Next Occurrence of the Word at Caret seems to do what you want." But I don't want just the "word at caret". I want to search for an entire phrase if highlighted. Have you tested it after selecting "foo and bar" and see if it selects the next instance of "foo and bar"?

Comment: I have indeed tested that and it does for me.

Comment: I'm using IDEA 2021.1.2 and "Next Occurrence of the Word at Caret" is very erratic. Sometimes I'll select something like `Optional<FooBar>` and it will find the next occurrence. But sometimes it stops working until I do some arbitrary sequence of "Find" or "Find Next". In addition if I do a manual "Find", it doesn't populate "Next Occurrence of the Word at Caret" with the text, because this functionality doesn't seem to be linked to the "Find" functionality. And finally "Next Occurrence of the Word at Caret" only matches with exact case; case insensitivity isn't supported. It's a broken mess.

Comment: The Quick Find plugin seems to work, though; thanks! Please edit your answer to refer only to the Quick Find plugin so that I can accept the answer (and/or split your answer into two answers, because they are different answers). I can't accept the "Next Occurrence of the Word at Caret" answer because it is flaky.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer.